# Variable within method not updating when running after time.sleep(10) - python

Tags: python, recursion

My goal is to output the current time every 10 seconds but for some reason the value does not update and it only prints the original time.

```
def runTest():
    
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(current_time)
    time.sleep(10)
    runTest()
```

output:

```
18:25:08
18:25:08
18:25:08
```

Comment: Could you correct the formatting of your code? It does not look correct, as the function definition is not part of code block. This might already be part of the problem. Also some imports seem to be missing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more details. We cannot answer you if you do not include the code you wrote. See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` should assign a different value to `current_time` according to what time it is when the assignment occurs. Why? Did the value of `now` change in the meantime? How?

Comment: This function never returns to unwind the recursion, so you will eventually overflow your stack.  Of course, at 10 seconds per recursion, it will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling the now function before you call the runTest function, instead of calling it within the function. See below, which does what you want:

```
import time, datetime

def runTest():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    time.sleep(10)
    runTest()

runTest()
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put datetime.now(), I only had now(). stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues in your code:

1. No need for recursion
2. The current time needs to be computed every time you loop:

Just do:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def runTest():
  while True:
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(current_time)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Recursion is useful only if the I/O of the recursion is used between recursions

Comment: thank you so much!, turns out I was being very silly and simply forgot to have datetime.now(), i only had now()